# dont understand BMI-Body Mass Index code beginner "Programming 1"

Tags: c#

Body Mass Index program console window version since im learning with Programming 1 course its essentially before object oriented stuff.
i cant seem to understand what im doing wrong as it says
Error   CS0019  Operator '^' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'double
and i have no clue what im doing wrong and are completely lost! :(

```
namespace BMI_o_BMR
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double weight, height, bmi, bmr;
            
            string gender; // Female f = kvinna, male m = man


            Console.WriteLine("Vi ska räkna ut ditt BMI och BMR");

            Console.WriteLine("Write your height");
            weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Write Your weight");
            height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Write your age");
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (height >= 0.50 && height <= 2.20 && weight >= 10 && weight <= 250 && age >= 18 && age <= 70)
            {
                bmi = (weight * 1.3) / height ^ 2.5;
                Console.WriteLine(bmi);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("choose your Gender M for Male or F for Female");
            

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What operation do you expect ^ to be? In c# its the XOR Operation so double can't use it. Do you wanted to use [Math.Exp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.exp?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: The `^` is a bitwise XOR operator. You need `Math.Pow(double, double)` or `Math.Exp`

Comment: By the way, I always thought that BMI equals Weigth/square(length), where do the 1.3 and the exponent 2.5 suddenly come from? :-)

Comment: thats what i got from my teacher :/

Comment: Maybe he is teaching BASIC ... not C# ... in C/C++/C#/Java/javascript/python ... `^` is not a power operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# `^` is either a [boolean logical XOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-) or [bitwise logical XOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-) ([C# operators and expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)).

Use [`Math.Pow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=net-7.0):

> Returns a specified number raised to the specified power.

```
bmi = (weight * 1.3) / Math.Pow(height, 2.5);
```

Comment: thank you not sure why we are suppose to do this when we only have learned int double and float and if / else and switch :/

Comment: @KimAlmighty maybe  the task/example was translated from another language which handles `^` as raise to power operator. But in general being able to search and find information is a great trait for student/programmer.

Comment: search and find is gonna be a bit new/hard and then actually understand what im looking at is a whole other dimension to that .. but thank you for the help very kind of you :)